# Insert Pallet Rack storage into a database

Tags: anylogic

I would like to insert the storage of my different pallet racks into a database. Problem is that I can't connect the type "other" "PalletRack" with the database. How could I do this? The aim is to connect it with my function to find out if my PalletRacks have enough space to store the pallets. 
[spaceAvailable-function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZxt8.png)
[parameter_storage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RsXqX.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should have your pallet racks defined in the database with an id number... Then you can add the history in the database using the pallet rack id every time the quantity changes, or you can just update the column "quantity" from your pallet racks table.

But you can't insert something of type PalletRack on a database.